# Can not add more than two row to Table programatically using VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-table

I have a grid view, which I have add a search button to it. when user clicked on this button a RadWindow opens, that contains a table which I have some fields in it. I have another botton inside RadWindow which user can add new row to table and create new condition.

all these elements are created programatically in grid view's RowCreated event as below:

```
     _updSearchBox = New UpdatePanel() With {.ID = "IdeaSearchBoxUpd" + ID.ToString(), .Page = Page}

                _imgSearch = New ImageButton() With {.ImageUrl = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "IdeaComponent.Search.png"), .ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled, .ID = "_imgSearch"}
                _imgSearch.ToolTip = "Search"
                _imgSearch.Attributes.Add("style", "margin:1px;border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;")

                e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(_imgSearch)

                winSearch = New RadWindow() With {.AutoSize = True, .Modal = True, .Behaviors = WindowBehaviors.None, .CenterIfModal = True}

                _btnCreateNewCondition = New Button() With {.Text = "New Condition", .ID = "_btnCreateNewCondition"}

                _tblSearch = New Table() 
                _tblSearch.Style.Add("direction", "rtl")
                _tblSearch.Style.Add("padding", "5")
                _tblSearch.Rows.Add(FilltheTableRow(CreateNewTableRow()))

                winSearch.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(_tblSearch)

                Dim ptCreateNewConditiob As AsyncPostBackTrigger = New AsyncPostBackTrigger()
                ptCreateNewConditiob.ControlID = "_btnCreateNewCondition"
                ptCreateNewConditiob.EventName = "Click"
                _updSearchBox.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_btnCreateNewCondition)
                _updSearchBox.Triggers.Add(ptCreateNewConditiob)

                _btnExecuteCondition = New Button() With {.Text = "OK", .ID = "_btnExecuteCondition"}
                Dim ptExecuteCondition As AsyncPostBackTrigger = New AsyncPostBackTrigger()
                ptExecuteCondition.ControlID = "_btnCreateNewCondition"
                ptExecuteCondition.EventName = "Click"
                _updSearchBox.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_btnExecuteCondition)
                _updSearchBox.Triggers.Add(ptExecuteCondition)

                _btnCancelCondition = New Button() With {.Text = "Cancel", .ID = "_btnCancelCondition"}
                _updSearchBox.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_btnCancelCondition)

                winSearch.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(_updSearchBox)
                e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(winSearch)
```

When user click on Create New Condition I call these codes:

```
 Dim row = FilltheTableRow(CreateNewTableRow())
        _tblSearch.Rows.Add(row)
```

Which the methods are:

```
        Private Function CreateNewTableRow() As TableRow

        Dim tableRow As TableRow = New TableRow()
        Dim tableCell1 As TableCell = New TableCell()
        Dim tableCell2 As TableCell = New TableCell()
        Dim tableCell3 As TableCell = New TableCell()
        Dim tableCell4 As TableCell = New TableCell()

        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell1)
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell2)
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell3)
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell4)

        Return tableRow

    End Function

    Private Function FilltheTableRow(ByVal row As TableRow) As TableRow

        Dim ddlFieldsList As DropDownList = New DropDownList()
        ddlFieldsList.Items.Add("F1")
        ddlFieldsList.Items.Add("F2")
        ddlFieldsList.Items.Add("F3")
        row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(ddlFieldsList)

        Dim ddlConditionsList As DropDownList = New DropDownList()
        ddlConditionsList.Items.Add("=")
        ddlConditionsList.Items.Add("<>")
        ddlConditionsList.Items.Add("LIKE")
        row.Cells(1).Controls.Add(ddlConditionsList)

        Dim txtConditionValue As TextBox = New TextBox()
        row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(txtConditionValue)

        Dim ddlConditionJointList As DropDownList = New DropDownList()
        ddlConditionJointList.Items.Add("AND")
        ddlConditionJointList.Items.Add("OR")
        ddlConditionJointList.Items.Add("IN")
        row.Cells(3).Controls.Add(ddlConditionJointList)

        Return row

    End Function
```

all these codes are run for first click on New Condition button and new row added to table and shown, but after first click, other clicks, run the code successfully without error but does not create new row any more.
would you please help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to initialize my table in On_Init event. and this solved my problem